# AsymptoticIntegrate of a difficult integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, asymptotics, asymptoticintegrate

I would like to use `AsymptoticIntegrate` to address [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4006080/asymptotics-or-methods-for-this-integral):  to get an asymptotic expression for:

$$\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\sin (\sin x)}{\Gamma (x+1)} \ln \left( \frac{1 + \Gamma (x+1)}{1+x} \right)\ dx$$

My (likely naive) approach was this:

```
AsymptoticIntegrate[
 Sin[Sin[a x]]/Gamma[x + 1] Log[(1 + Gamma[x + 1])/(1 + x)], 
 {x, 0, ∞},
 {a, 1, 5}]
```

thinking that searching for an answer when $a \to 1$.  Alas, this took a long time to compute and ultimately yielded no relevant solution.

What is the proper approach?

Comment: Ummm... why the downvote?

Comment: Why the need for an asymptotic expression when `NIntegrate` seems to work just fine:  `NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, WorkingPrecision -> 75]` results in 0.00579632757579270447211888094005514037166465505508585501007792924174572629608.

Comment: @JimB:  I duplicated the numerical integration specified in the original problem on Math.SE, of course.  My goal is to get a *symbolic* answer, as these can often give insights into the mathematical structure of a problem.  After all, if all one ever needed was the final numerical value, why would *Mathematica* ever include `AsymptoticIntegral` anyway?  That's why.

Comment: I don't have to tell you that not all definite integrals have nice symbolic results.  And `AsymptoticIntegrate` seems to only promise an approximation.  (It would have been nice if the downvoter explained the downvote.)

Comment: @JimB in principle it would be nice to have an explanation every time we see a downvote... David a related question: do you want the full computation automated? I mean would you consider some manual algebraic manipulations like the ones suggested in Math.S.E in order to massage the integrand?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but how long does this code take to run? I wait for several minutes, but the calculation doesn't finish. If it simply never finishes, it's better to mention  this in the question.

Comment: In addtion to what was pointed out by @xzczd I aborted the computation of the OP after ten minutes because it did not return anything. To the author of the OP: can you be more precise? It's a very vague statement `Alas, this took a long time to compute and ultimately yielded no relevant solution.` How long did it take and what was the solution?

Comment: I did not downvote, but I find the whole question a bit senseless: 1. The post on math.stackexchange asks for good numerical method. Why one needs to invent something if MA has `NIntegrate`? 2. One may ask about the analytic value, but it is out of reach. 3. Artificially introduced parameter `a` does not promise any progress because the dependence likely to be oscillatory.

Comment: $+1$ from me, because you took the time and the effort to write that question! (Thank you!)

Answer (score 5):

## **Edit: there's a factor of `2` missing from the RHS of the $\sin(\sin x)$ relation, which follows from a mistake/typo in the Maths.S.E answer for which I provided a link. I grateful to @yarchik for bringing this to my attention.**

---

## **Not an answer, but I need some feedback and someone else could -perhaps- continue in this line.**

---

Some comments:

> 1. There's already some ambiguity in the OP from the maths site.

> 2. Regarding the code provided in the OP. I let Mathematica do its things for ten minutes and it did not return anything, so I aborted. I am using 13.2.0 on a mac. So I am not sure what to do with the vague comment, **this took a long time to compute and ultimately yielded no relevant solution.** Not even sure I believe it as a piece of info to be honest.

> 3. The only reason I am writing some stuff below is that I wasted some time already and some other users have done so as well. May the following observation prove a helpful hint to the rest.

We consider

$$
\begin{equation}
\int^{\infty}_{0} dx ~ \frac{\sin (\sin x)}{\Gamma (x+1)} \ln \left( \frac{1 + \Gamma (x+1)}{1+x} \right)
\end{equation}
$$

The first thing we can use is [**`the following relation`**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2782139/how-to-find-the-indefinite-integral-of-sinsinxdx) in the above

$$
\begin{equation}
\sin (\sin x) = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} J_{2k+1}(1) \sin\left((2k+1)x\right)
\end{equation}
$$

Taking from the comments in the link in the OP we consider the Taylor expansions in large and small `x`

```
Sin[(2 k + 1) x] 1/Gamma[x + 1] Log[(1 + Gamma[x + 1])/(1 + x)] // 
  Series[#, {x, 0, 1}] & // Normal
Sin[(2 k + 1) x] 1/Gamma[x + 1] Log[(1 + Gamma[x + 1])/(1 + x)] // 
  Series[#, {x, Infinity, 1}] & // Normal
```

> [image: taylors]

Now, we can check with the following definitions

```
tstlowx[inf_] := 
 Sum[BesselJ[2 k + 1, 1] (1 + 2 k) x Log[2], {k, 0, inf}]
tstlargex[inf_] := 
 Sum[BesselJ[2 k + 1, 1] (
   E^(x (1 - Log[x]))
     Log[1/x + (E^(x (-1 + Log[x])) Sqrt[2 \[Pi]])/Sqrt[
      x]] Sin[(1 + 2 k) x])/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Sqrt[x]), {k, 0, inf}]
```

that the low-`x` expression

```
Table[N@tstlowx[xx], {xx, 1, 7}]
```

> [image: lowx]

and for the large-`x`

> [image: largex]

Again following the comments in the maths question, one can imagine using Stirling's formula for the $\Gamma$ and the relation that simplifies $\sin (\sin (x))$. I have checked that the situation does not simplify -at least nothing I could spot

```
Sin[(2 k + 1) x] 1/(Sqrt[2 Pi x] (x/E)^x)
    Log[(1 + Sqrt[2 Pi x] (x/E)^x)/(1 + x)] // 
  Series[#, {x, 0, 1}] & // Normal
Sin[(2 k + 1) x] 1/(Sqrt[2 Pi x] (x/E)^x)
    Log[(1 + Sqrt[2 Pi x] (x/E)^x)/(1 + x)] // 
  Series[#, {x, Infinity, 1}] & // Normal
```

> [image: stirling]

Comment: Actually, I do not know who originated this formula for $\sin(\sin x)$, but it is not correct, there is a factor of two missing.

Comment: @yarchik thanks for your comment. I included a link from Maths.S.E in my original response. is it not working for you? I checked that it is still active. Let me know so I can update it

Comment: The formula is wrong, rhs should be multiplied by 2. Do not trust some random links.

Comment: @yarchik, ok thanks for letting me know. I managed to find that as well from some other discussion on Maths.S.E. I will update with a comment, but honestly do not have the courage to re-run the commands. Sorry...

Comment: If you managed to obtain good results from the wrong formula --- something is wrong with your method :)

Comment: @yarchik it is easy to check that a factor of `2` will not terribly destroy anything, mainly because I just re-wrote the $\sin(\sin)$ as a $\sin$ and just massaged a bit the integrand. I did not manage to compute the integral which was the main thing.

Comment: Helpful... thanks!  ($+1$)

Comment: @yarchik This is called Jacobi-Anger expansion (or Jacobi–Anger identity): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=jacobi-anger+expansion

Comment: @xzczd so indeed there was a factor of `2` missing. hats off to both of you :-)